# Simple Jenkins pipeline fails when I check an environment variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my multibranch pipeline job, I can successfully access environment variables like this:

```
echo "$env.BRANCH_NAME"
```

But it throws and exception if I try to compare against that same environment variable:

```
if($env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master')
{
  echo "This is the master branch"
}
```

Here's the top of the error stack I'm given:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $env for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:4)
```

Do I need to do some sort of script approval here?  I checked in Manage Jenkins -> In-Process Script Approval, but nothing is there.

Answer (score 8):

Try to remove the dollar sign or use `"${env.BRANCH_NAME}"`

Comment: it worked when I changed it to if("$env.BRANCH_NAME" == 'release')

Answer (score 4):

The earlier answer is correct, but for more information, the "$var" syntax is what is used within a string to interpolate the variable value into the string.  Outside of a string, just reference the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $ to interpolate variables, any of this options will work:

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master')
{
  echo "This is the master branch"
}
```

or

```
if("$env.BRANCH_NAME" == 'master')
{
  echo "This is the master branch"
}
```